# Sequelize findAll with Not Null

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I try to get all active users that in the deleted_at column is empty.

```
Model.findAll({
    raw: true,
    where: {
        user_id: user_id,
        status: true,
        deleted_at: {
            $ne: null
        }
    },
    attributes: ['name']
}).map(el => el.get('name'));
```

This always return empty value, in my database i have one row with `deleted_at: null`.

What's the correct way of do this ?

Comment: You sure don't want to use `options.paranoid`?
https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/model.js~Model.html#static-method-findAll

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add `paranoid: true` to your Model Sequelize will automatically include a SQL query for "where deleted_at is not null". You add this in the model and remove your extra where config in the controller.